# middleman localizing entire templates not working

Tags: localization, middleman

I am building a web site using

- middleman 3
- prototype template extension
- en (English language) as default root language

According to this documentation

http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/localization/#toc_6

```
source/localizable/services.en.html.haml
source/localizable/services.es.html.haml
```

should generate

```
build/services.html
build/es/services.html
```

but `bundle exec middleman build` generates

```
build/services.en.html
build/services.es.html
build/es/services.en.html
build/es/services.es.html
```

I have tried moving both templates to root folder and not working.

Comment: This seems to be prepared for content-negotiation. If this webserver feature is activated, the request of services.html will be answered with services.en.html

This can be quite handy as the user gets automatically the page in his language if available. more: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html

Comment: Thank for the input @salout. Middleman is supposed to handle that without the need of Apache web server.

Comment: Check out this issue: https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/1015

It got fixed already, so you might want to try the development (master) version of middleman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @rriemann link, the [Localizing whole templates does not work bug](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/1015) was reported on Sept 21, 2013 and [fixed](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/1015#ref-commit-4427c4b) on Nov 1, 2013.

The issue was closed on Dec 1, 2013.